# Identify a sci-fi novel where the narrator is a woman who describes a community of low-tech farmers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I only remember the beginning. A woman from a small community is describing two barbarians who have been captured and put to work. The community seems to be low tech farmers and the barbarians are even less developed. The community is some kind of collective and they don't use pronouns like "I", "we", "me", "you". Instead of saying "I would be tired" they say something like "a body is tired". I think the narrator's partner recently died. One of the barbarians may be called Ain the Axe. Also there might be some kid of climate issues or falling  meteor storms.

Comment: When did you read this?  Do you remember any cover art?  How long was it, what language was it in?  Is it set in a post-apocalyptic future, an alternate Earth, or a fantasy world?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @DavidW - It doesn't sound very scifi.

Comment: @Valorum You're not wrong, but neither is *Conan*.  Actually, even *The Gate to Women's Country* wouldn't sound very SF at this level of detail.

Comment: Please at least edit in why you think this story is scifi.

Comment: @DavidW - Conan isn't at all Scifi. It is, however, Fantasy.

Comment: @Valorum \*sigh\*  Okay, here; you can wear my "Accredited Pedant" pin for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 7):

The language around pronouns sounds familiar… like the way the Runa speak in Mary Doria Russell's science fiction novel [*The Sparrow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sparrow_(novel)) (and in it's sequel [*Children of God*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_God_(novel))).

The Runa community could be described as rural, who are initially nomadic foragers, but on the way to becoming agriculturalists under the guidance of the human PoV characters.

One of the PoV characters loses a partner.

Another social group (and, for that matter ecological group), the Jana'ata are quite barbaric to the Runa and to some of the humans.

Unsure about characters with the name "Ain" or "Axe," but one of the characters is "Anne".

Although a spaceship-ified asteroid figures in the novel, I do not recall meteors. Climate change on Earth may be part of the setting, but is not foregrounded.